# How do you use HTML <button> tag for changing pages in html

Tags: html

I'm more of a new coder, but I cant figure out how to make a button go to a new page, if you wanted to see, this is my code, most of my CSS or stylesheet is inline, I'm mainly building this to be a website for my school news, I also cant find many things about this

**Code:**

```css
.line-1 {
  height: 10px;
  align-self: center;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 3px;
  transform: translateY(-50px);
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <style>
    body {
   height: 3000px;
   background: linear-gradient(0.2deg, rgb(60, 0, 80) 0%, rgb(30, 0, 51) 51%, rgb(6, 0, 27) 75%);
      }
      h1 {
          text-align: center;
          color: yellow;
          font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
          font-size: 80px;
          border-radius: 5px;
      }  
      p {
          position: relative;
          bottom: 50px;
          text-align: center;
          color: yellow;
          font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
          font-size: 20px;
      }
      button {
        font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
         background-color: yellow;
         border: 5px solid yellow;
         color: white;
         padding: 15px 30px;
         text-align: center;
         text-decoration: none;
         display: inline-block;
         font-size: 28px;
         color: rgb(6, 0, 40);
         position: relative;
          bottom: 50px;
          border-radius: 5px;
          curser: hover;
          curser: ;
          transition-duration: 0.4s;
      }
      button:hover {
         background-color: rgb(6, 0, 40); 
         color: yellow;
         padding: 12px 24px;
      };
      body {
          background-color: darkblue;
      };
  </style>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>-MVP-</h1>
  <h1>-News-</h1>
     <div class="line-1"></div>  
     <p>The Moran Newsline</p> 
     <center>
     <button type="button" onclick="alert('Test.More')">More</button>
     <button type="button" onclick="alert('Test.Broadcasts')">Broadcasts</button>
     <button type="button" onclick="alert('Test.Info')">Info</button>
      </center> 
</body>
</html>
```

So how would I make this work?

Comment: I think an anchor is what you need instead of a button. Checkout [HTML <a> Tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

to make your button open a page you need to add a link in the button tag.
Like this:

```
 <button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='writeYourPageHere.com';">Test</button>
```

Comment: @GuyInABox what do you mean by > im not using .com? < you are also using css in your html file, but i think you also have a .css file so why not put the css code in your html file in the .css file?

Comment: Okay let me know. I think it should work